# Want larger icons in browser shortcut tiles (Win10)

Tags: icons, tiles

I have a bunch of browser shortcuts pinned to my Start menu. The shortcuts are in Windows>Start Menu and all have custom icons, selected via Properties but the icons appear on the tiles smaller than I'd like.
I also have a few folders on my network drive pinned to my Start menu and I figured out how to give them custom icons and they are the same size as the ones for the shortcuts.

I would like to make the icons appear larger on the tiles. I wouldn't mind being able to custom color the tiles too.

I have used Tileiconifier to massage the appearance of a few app tiles but it doesn't find the shortcuts so it can't change them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: Firefox is the default browser but a couple of the shortcuts are set up to open in Chrome. But that won't make any difference to the size of the icons on the Start menu tiles for the shortcuts.